# Routing with NextJs in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, routes

I'm trying to create a react app with NextJs, but the routing is not working. The homepage is working, but with my other page, which is my detail-page, it just says 404 error.

This is how my folder and project structure looks like:
[image]

```
const detail = () => {
    return(
        <h1>Detail side</h1>
    )
}

export default detail();
```

Comment: You should rename `detail.tsx` to `index.tsx`

Comment: Not directly related to your question but you want your component to start with a capital letter and export the component instead of creating a function and calling it to return.

Comment: But i already have a file called index.tsx, which is my main page. I want a routing called localhost:xxxx/detail

Comment: Either rename file inside /detail directory to index.tsx or move the detail.tsx file directly to pages folder. @technophyle mentioned you should (not need) name components with capital letter and you can't invoke component while returning it, so it should only be: `export default detail;`

Comment: What do you use for routes ? `react-router` ?

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, and i'm beginning to use Nextjs as routing in React.